# Odd use of the Community account.

Tags: discussion

I noticed that the community account was used to add a comment to the content of a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/help-cleaning-up-file-accessing-code). The comment doesn't look very automated and probably would have been better off as a proper comment attributed to the actual user making the comment.

Can anyone provide insights into why it was done this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I approved the edit, I was under the assumption that the edit was made by the OP (who is not registered on code review).

Now that I look at it again, I see that that was probably wrong. It seems I didn't pay close enough attention. I have reverted the edit now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: On the off chance the OP is reading this, I would encourage you to to create a CodeReview account and have the post ownership assigned to you.

Comment: @brian this was an edit by an anonymous user that someone approved, to be clear